# We are using Sybase/ODBC how to deal with disconnects while running long batch SQL queries?

Tags: database, connection, odbc, sybase, disconnect

We are developping an application in C# that uses ODBC and the "Adaptive server enterprise" driver to extract data from a Sybase DB.

We have a long SQL batch query that create a lot of intermediate temporary tables and returns several DataTable objects to the application. We are seeing exceptions saying `TABLENAME not found` where *TABLENAME* is one of our intermediate temporary tables. When I check the status of the OdbcConnection object in the debugger it is `Closed`.

My question is very general. Is this the price you pay for having long-running complicated queries? Or is there a reliable way to get rid of such spurious disconnects?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ODBC timeout parameters - see SDK docs at:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20116.1550/html/aseodbc/CHDCGBEH.htm

Specifically CommandTimeOut and ConnectionTimeOut which you can set accordingly.

But much more likely is you're being blocked or similar when the process is running - maybe ask your DBA to check your query plan for the various steps in your batch and look for specific problem areas such as tablescans etc which could be masking your timeout issue.